# Why isn't this listener being triggered

Tags: extjs4

I have the following view I have defined:

```
    Ext.define("app.view.stock.SearchValueField", {
        extend: "Ext.form.field.Text",
        alias: "widget.searchvaluefield",
        name: "search_value_field",
        enableKeyEvents: true,
        allowBlank: false,
        listeners: [
            {
                keyup: {
                    fn: function(){console.log('logged');}
                }
            }
        ],
        initComponent: function() {
            this.callParent(arguments);
        }
    });
```

But on keyup the listener isn't being triggered. I am quite well versed in the mvc architecture so please assume that the other parts of my app are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide an `Object` for the `listeners` config parameter, as described in the [Observable documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-cfg-listeners).
You used an `Array`. It works using the following code:

```
Ext.define("app.view.stock.SearchValueField", {
  extend: "Ext.form.field.Text",
  alias: "widget.searchvaluefield",
  name: "search_value_field",
  enableKeyEvents: true,
  allowBlank: false,
  listeners: {
    keyup: function() { 
      console.log('logged');
    },
  },
  // actually the 'empty' override of initComponent isn't necessary
  initComponent: function() {
    this.callParent(arguments);
  }
});
```